# Principal Context object returns null after hosting application in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, principal

Below is my code:

```
public List<ActiveDirectory> GetActiveDirectoryUsers(string user = "")
        {
            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Constants.DomainName);

            if (user == "User")
            {
                adUsers = GetSpecificGroupUsers(ctx, Constants.UserGroup);
            }
            else
            {
                adUsers = GetSpecificGroupUsers(ctx, Constants.AdminGroup);
                adUsers = GetSpecificGroupUsers(ctx, Constants.UserGroup);
            }

            ctx.Dispose();       
            return adUsers;
        }

        public List<ActiveDirectory> GetSpecificGroupUsers(PrincipalContext ctx,string groupName)
        {
            GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName);

            if (grp != null)
            {
                foreach (Principal p in grp.GetMembers(false))
                {
                    if (p.DisplayName != null)
                    {
                        adUsers.Add(new ActiveDirectory()
                         {
                             UserName = p.DisplayName,
                             DisplayName = p.SamAccountName
                        });

                    }
                }

                grp.Dispose();

            }

            return adUsers;
        }
```

The above code works in Visual studio editor (in dev environment). But the Principal Context object returns null after hosting the application in IIS. I have used form authentication and not windows authentication as I need a custom login page.

This line is throwing error:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Constants.DomainName);
```

Where `Constants.DomainName` = "My_Domain_Name".

Please let me know if there is any way to sort it out.

Thanks for reading and kindly give some suggestions.

Comment: did you given enough permission to application pool?

Comment: How to give permission to app pool? I am getting this error -'ctx.connected server throw an exception of type system.directoryservicesComexception'

Comment: https://support.appliedi.net/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/768/0/how-to-manually-create-a-site--application-pool-identity-in-iis7